# calculate the distance using longitude and latitude in vb using array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

i am writing a windows application to find distance using latitude and longitude . I have more than 100 numbers of value in array  and got this formula to find the distance

```
Dim theta As Double = lon1 - lon2
Dim dist As Double = Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(theta))
dist = Math.Acos(dist)
dist = rad2deg(dist)
dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
dist = dist * 1.609344
```

i have to  arrange the value for lat1,lat2,lon1,lon2 ? 
  any suggestion how can i arrange the array that i pass the value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, decide on a container to store each coordinate, perhaps a structure or class.

```
Public Class Coordinate
    Public Latitude As Double
    Public Longitude As Double

    Public Sub New(ByVal lon As Double, ByVal lat As Double)
        Latitude = lat
        Longitude = lon
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then you'll need a collection to store all of your coordinates, maybe a list or a dictionary (if you want to reference them by an index).

```
Public Coordinates as As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Coordinate)
```

Then your assignments,

```
Coordinates.Add(1, New Coordinate(654.321, 123.456))
Coordinates.Add(2, New Coordinate(321.654, 456.123))
```

You can build your function to accept your custom container as input.

```
Public Function CalcDistance(ByVal coord1 As Coordinate, ByVal coord2 As Coordinate) As Double
    Dim lon1 As Double = coord1.Longitude
    Dim lat1 As Double = coord1.Latitude
    Dim lon2 As Double = coord2.Longitude
    Dim lat2 As Double = coord2.Latitude
    'Do math!
    Return dist
End Function
```

Finally, call your function, pass it values, and magic happens!

```
Dim distanceBetween As Double = CalcDistance(Coordinates(1), Coordinates(2))
```

**Update:** A user control seems like a terrible place to store data, so I'm reluctant to provide this, but since it's your second attempt at posting this question, here's a simple way to use what you've got.

```
Public Function CalcDistance(ByVal lon1 As Double, ByVal lat1 As Double, ByVal lon2 As Double, ByVal lat2 As Double) As Double
    'Do Math!
    Return dist
End Function

Dim distanceBetween As Double = CalcDistance(CDbl(ListBox1.Items(0).Value), CDbl(ListBox2.Items(0).Value), CDbl(ListBox1.Items(1).Value), CDbl(ListBox2.Items(1).Value))
```